# List Open Graph nodes associated with a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Assuming:

- I am an admin of a Facebook app
- I've associated some webpages to the app using Open Graph protocol meta tags, as described [on Facebook's site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)
- I know or can acquire basic info about the app, such as its app ID

Is there a way to get a list of all such associated pages?  Whether by an API that Facebook exposes, or anything.

EDIT: (further details for clarification)

I'm talking about webpages (not Facebook pages) which are associated to a Facebook app by way of Open Graph meta tags.  For example, adding this to a webpage's markup:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567"/>
```

You can then publish messages to Likers of individual pages, or Likers of all pages associated with the app.

All of this is described on [the Facebook Open Graph page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) I linked to above.

So, to reiterate, I want to know if you can get from Facebook a list of all such associated pages.

Comment: *Bump*  Does anyone know?  Or can anyone confirm that it is definitely not possible?

Answer (score -1):

Pistos

When you set up your app you set the domain and cavans url.  The only website which can connect to that applications is the domain set in the settings.

To retrieve your Application Id goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps  select your app in the list on left and you will see all basic info including links to edit settings.

Comment: A single application can host only one domain.  When you configure the Domain in application Settings all sub domains and directories are included.  A list is not created of all included urls though, so the answer to this is no.