# How to get Open Graph objects associated with an application or Facebook user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I recently set up a Facebook application so that I might be able to [send messages to people who 'like' things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790503/165988)). I managed to figure that part out, but now I'm stumped again.

As far as I have seen, every open graph object that is created will have a reference to a `app_id` if the page had a `fb:app_id` open graph meta tag. However, I haven't seen anything in the Open Graph API that allows me to get a list of Open Graph objects associated with an app_id ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7211216/165988) has some insight, but doesn't provide a lot of information).

Alternatively, since I know that the pages will have a similar URL, I was investigating FQL to see if it is possible to find pages where the URL matches some pattern (either using `strpos` or the `IN` operator). No luck there either (condition fields needs to be indexed).

Lastly, I considered using the `fb:admin` metatag, because apparently it is possible to [see which pages a user administers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628836/165988). In this case, I haven't figured out how to become administrator of the Open Graph object, so I am again stumped.

**Is there any way, however roundabout, to get open graph objects associated with a Facebook application or user?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get a list (from Facebook) of objects it knows are associated with a given app_id. Facebook only "knows" about your custom OG objects when it crawls them, and its only going to crawl them in when an action is taken with your OG object as a target. The best way to keep track of OG object for a given app is to track the result of OG API calls that create these actions (you'll get an fb_action_id).

Same with users. You can track which users are associated with your App in response to successful calls to FB.login or FB.getLoginStatus. You'll need to track actions taken by that user yourself.